# Possible to toggle layers and utilize compositing between layers

Tags: mapbox

I've implemented the "Layers" toggling in Mapbox.js and was hoping to be able to toggle layers on and off while the layers interact together with "comp-op: darken;"

I think the problem is the z-score with the layers being specifically ordered?

Answer (score 0):

`comp-op: darken;` is a CartoCSS rule. By the time that you've used that rule in TileMill and put your map on Mapbox, whatever style rules and data you used is now just normal tile images, and so compositing them will do exactly what layering other images on the internet will do (basically A+B). It's similar to, for instance, filters in Photoshop: the JPEG you export doesn't contain the filters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My goal is to toggle the layers on/off while keeping comp-op: darken; operating between layers http://alexbhill.github.io/county-flows/

Comment: @tmcw Does cartoCSS works with mapbox-gl-js ? I can't figure out how to do layers compositing

Comment: No, it doesn't.